# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013: Unable to invoke command "Format Document"

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2013

During `Format Document` command in razor cshtml file, I am getting the following message in Visual Studio 2013:

> Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

Anyone having similar issue? Is there a known workaround for that?

Comment: It looks like it's possible a bug.  Can you provide some more detail though.  Does it happen when you format the whole document or only with specific selections?  Does it happen with every file or just specific ones?

Comment: Only certain files, not everyone. `Format Selection` works, but not if I select the whole file.